# Check matrix element

Tags: matlab, matrix, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

I need a `(rho,theta)` `meshgrid` and to do that first I defined the `meshgrid` in Cartesian coordinates and then convert it to polar coordinates:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
R = sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2);
PHI = atan2(Y,X);
```

Now what I get is a mesh in polar coordinates, but since it is a squared mesh, I get this thing

[image]

I say that the values greater than `R` are  wrong and therefore I set them to zero. I did it in this way

```
for i = 1:1:length(R)
    for j = 1:1:length(R)
        if R(i,j) > a
            R(i,j) = 0;
        else
            R(i,j);
        end
    end
end
```

How can I do this less convoluted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For direct Cartesian to polar conversion of coordinates: use [`cart2pol`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cart2pol.html).

```
[theta,rho] = cart2pol(x,y)
```

Then a simple logical check will do:

```
tmp = rho>R;
rho(tmp)=0; %=[] to delete completely
theta(tmp)=0;
```

For what it's worth: you can of course create a direct polar grid:

```
[theta,rho] = meshgrid(0:dtheta:theta,0:dR:R)
```

Finally: [`i` and `j` denote the imaginary unit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14790740/5211833) in MATLAB, and I'd argue against using them as regular variables for reasons mentioned in this post, but that's my opinion.

Comment: I thought to create a polar grid directly but I was having issues to plot the results using `quiver` due to the different dimension of the matrix `theta` and `rho`. With the solution that I choose (cartesian-polar-cartesian again) I have a squared mesh, easier to manage

Comment: @Shika93 you could just make your `theta` and `rho` vectors which you feed to `meshgrid` the same length, and then `quiver` is fine with it. Anyway the `cart2pol` does basically the same as what you did by hand, just wrapped in a handy function.

Answer (score 1):

If we say that `a` is the limit you want to use you can use below code instead of the for loop:

```
R = (R<=a).*R
```

Or you can use as well:

```
R(R>a) = 0
```

Comment: Just notice that in your code you used `R` to denote radius and `a` to denote the limit. Whereas in the figure you use `R` as the limit and `rho` for radius. I used the notation you stated in your code.

Comment: I like the second option. Oh yes I didn't follow the notation that I used in my code inside the image, sorry. It was just to clarify what I needed. Thanks